# How to connect my two HTML pages using flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to link two html pages 'home.html' and 'result.html' using flask framework but it is not working. Also the changes that I make in html page are not reflecting when page is opened with flask.

Here's the code for 'home.html' :

```
<!doctype <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>IRIS PREDICTOR</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/static/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="text-info">IRIS PREDICTION</h1>
    <form action="/result" method="POST">
    <div class="col-2" id="abc">
        <label for="ex2">Sepal Length</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text" name="s_length">
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <label for="ex2">Sepal Width</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text" name="s_width">
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <label for="ex2">Petal Length</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text" name="p_length">
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <label for="ex2">Petal Width</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text" name="p_width">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon1">Predict</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for 'result.html':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>PREDICTION RESULT</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/static/style.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Sepal Length: {{sepal_length}}</p>
    <p>Sepal Width: {{sepal_width}}</p>
    <p>Petal Length: {{petal_length}}</p>
    <p>Petal Width: {{petal_width}}</p>
    <p>Species: {{predict_result}}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

And code for script.py is:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
from sklearn.externals import joblib

app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')

def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def show():
    if request.method=='POST':
        sepal_length=request.form['s_length']
        sepal_width=request.form['s_width']
        petal_length=request.form['p_length']
        petal_width=request.form['p_width']
        data=[[float(sepal_length),float(sepal_width),float(petal_length),float(petal_width)]]
        model=joblib.load('iris_model.pkl')
        predict_result=model.predict(data)

    return render_template('result.html',sepal_length=sepal_length,sepal_width=sepal_width,petal_length=petal_length,petal_width=petal_width,predict_result=predict_result)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

What should i do now?

Comment: I don't know how you are trying to connect the two pages but I think you should check [this](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#template-inheritance) out

Answer (score 2):

I have your code working. Your @app.route for the show function was for `/result` but home.html was posting the data to `/result/`
Also your button on home.html wasn't a submit button so it never posted the form.

Full listings of the files below

**script.py** - i've commented out the joblib items

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
#from sklearn.externals import joblib

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def show():
    if request.method=='POST':
        sepal_length=request.form['s_length']
        sepal_width=request.form['s_width']
        petal_length=request.form['p_length']
        petal_width=request.form['p_width']
        data=[[float(sepal_length),float(sepal_width),float(petal_length),float(petal_width)]]
        #model=joblib.load('iris_model.pkl')
        #predict_result=model.predict(data)
        predict_result="TEST"

    return render_template('result.html',sepal_length=sepal_length,sepal_width=sepal_width,petal_length=petal_length,petal_width=petal_width,predict_result=predict_result)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

**home.html**

```
<!doctype <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>IRIS PREDICTOR</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/static/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="text-info">IRIS PREDICTION</h1>
    <form action="/predict" method="POST">
    <div class="col-2" id="abc">
        <label for="ex2">Sepal Length</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text" name="s_length">
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <label for="ex2">Sepal Width</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text" name="s_width">
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <label for="ex2">Petal Length</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text" name="p_length">
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <label for="ex2">Petal Width</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text" name="p_width">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" id="button-addon1">Predict</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

result.html is unchanged from your example

Answer (score 0):

I hope the explanation below helps others in the future.

Please make sure that you save all 3 files in the same directory(folder). In the same folder you saved the script.py, create another folder and name it "templates". Place both html files in this folder. Then, run script.py in your terminal, you should see the output on the server.

Usually, the reason why changes are not reflecting in your page is because you might have forgotten to save the changes after they are made. One might think that it is automatically saved but it is not.

Answer (score -1):

Put your both templates in 'templates' directory where your scripts.py located. Flask search template files in 'templates' directory.
Remove space between @app.route and def home().